# How do I overlap a div with text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlap the text over the div below it. The problem is that I need it all in the bottom right of the page so it already has position: absolute.

This is what I currently have.

[image: current]

And this is what I'm trying to make it look like:

[image: target]

https://jsfiddle.net/7ow5p192/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.artist {
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.artist-container {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
}

.nameContain {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.nameContain2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="nameContain">
  <span class="title">Smells Like Teen Spirit</span>
  <div class="artist-container"><span class="artist">Nirvana</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `margin-top: -12px;` for the bottom `div` to get the overlap. Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yz0wavu5/

Answer (score 0):

A simple `text-align: right` should do the trick.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.title {
  color: white;
}

.artist {
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.artist-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
}

.nameContain {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;

  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="nameContain">
  <span class="title">Smells Like Teen Spirit</span>
  <div class="artist-container"><span class="artist">Nirvana</span></div>
</div>
```